# Calculate returns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am running a mysql - `10.1.39-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary`- database.

I want to calculate daily returns and I am having the following table:

```
| id   | date                | api_endpoint | ticker | open      | high      | low       | close     | volume    |
|------|---------------------|--------------|--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 18   | 2019-08-07 00:00:00 | daily        | AAPL   | 195.41000 | 199.56000 | 193.82000 | 199.04000 | 33364400  |
| 19   | 2019-08-06 00:00:00 | daily        | AAPL   | 196.31000 | 198.07000 | 194.04000 | 197.00000 | 35824800  |
| 20   | 2019-08-05 00:00:00 | daily        | AAPL   | 197.99000 | 198.65000 | 192.58000 | 193.34000 | 52393000  |
| 21   | 2019-08-02 00:00:00 | daily        | AAPL   | 205.53000 | 206.43000 | 201.62470 | 204.02000 | 40862100  |
| 44   | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | monthly      | AAPL   | 213.90000 | 218.03000 | 206.74000 | 208.43000 | 54017900  |
| 5273 | 1999-09-07 00:00:00 | monthly      | AAPL   | 73.75000  | 77.93800  | 73.50000  | 76.37500  | 246198400 |
```

As a result I would like to get:

```
| id | date             | ticker | close  | daily_return |
|----|------------------|--------|--------|--------------|
| 16 | 09.08.2019 00:00 | AAPL   | 200,99 | -1,20        |
| 17 | 08.08.2019 00:00 | AAPL   | 203,43 | 2,21         |
| 18 | 07.08.2019 00:00 | AAPL   | 199,04 | 1,04         |
| 19 | 06.08.2019 00:00 | AAPL   | 197    | 1,89         |
| 20 | 05.08.2019 00:00 | AAPL   | 193,34 | -5,23        |
| 21 | 02.08.2019 00:00 | AAPL   | 204,02 | -2,12        |
| 22 | 01.08.2019 00:00 | AAPL   | 208,43 | #DIV/0!      |
```

I am trying to use the following formula:

`(current_close - last_close)/last_close`

whereas `current_close` is at time `t` and `last_close` is at time `t - 1` (previous day)

I am struggeling getting the `last_close` price.

Any suggestions how to calculate the returns?

Comment: What are supposed to be `current_close` and `last_close` ? What have you done so far ? What is the expected output ?

Comment: @Cid `current_close` is the close on the current day(t), `last_close` is the close on the previous day(t-1)

Comment: Add the expected output (in tabular format) to the question, based on the given sample data in the question. Also, any chance of you being able to upgrade your MariaDB to latest version

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Please see my updated answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upgrade your MariaDB version to `10.2` or later, you could use `LAG` here:

```
SELECT *,
    (close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY date)) /
        LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS returns
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    date DESC;
```

For your version of MariaDB, we might have to resort to using correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT *,
    (close -
        (SELECT (t2.close) FROM yourTable t2
         WHERE t2.date < t1.date
         ORDER BY t2.date DESC LIMIT 1)) /
         (SELECT (t2.close) FROM yourTable t2
         WHERE t2.date < t1.date
         ORDER BY t2.date DESC LIMIT 1) AS returns
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    date DESC;
```

Comment: [Window functions were first introduced in MariaDB 10.2.0](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions/). OP is using `10.1.39-MariaDB`